# AngularJS2 RC6 component based on drop down

Tags: javascript, angular

I have recently started getting into AngularJS and it is a great little framework. I have been working on a prototype to prove how powerful it is to my colleagues with Angular2 RC6. I have run onto a little bit of an issue that I hope someoene can help me with.

I am writing a reporting framework which I am trying to keep as modular as possible. We have a list of reports (ReportOne, ReportTwo etc) which is listed in a dropdown box. Depending on what is selected I want to be able to load a certain module/component. My structure is as follows

```
-app
-- Modules
--- report.module.ts
--- report.component.ts
--- report.component.html
--- ReportOne
---- reportone.module.ts
---- reportone.component.ts
---- reportone.component.html
---- reportone.component.css
---- reportone.routing.ts
--- ReportTwo
---- reporttwo.module.ts
---- reporttwo.component.ts
---- reporttwo.component.html
---- reporttwo.component.css
---- reporttwo.routing.ts
-- app.module.ts
```

They are currently in modules as I was making route configs (/reports/{data}/reportone as I thought it was a great idea but then realised I couldn't keep the parent report.component.html styling as I am using the route-outlet tag.

Any help would be greatly appreciated I have gotten to a dead-end and due to my lack of experience with Angular I don't know where to start looking

**UPDATE:**
What I am looking for is for the component to change not the style. So it can have different services etc being injected as that'll be dependant on the report.

I would like to end up with something like

```
<report-container>
   <report-view></report-view>
</report-container
```

report-view will have a drop down with a list of reports that will render a component into report-view depending on what is selected in that drop down

Comment: im a little confused on what you are asking here. you want your parent html styling to match the styling of whatever report you select?

Comment: No each report could have different services etc. I want to add/render the component based on what's selected

Comment: Sorry was in a bit of a rush this morning. So what want to do is have something like

Comment: Sorry  pressed enter now it won't let me edit

Sorry was in a bit of a rush this morning. So what want to do is have something like

    <report-container>
       <report-view></report-view>
    </report-container

report-view will have a drop down with a list of reports that will render a component into report-view depending on what is selected in that drop down